# symfony2 JMS extra security bundle @secure controller

Tags: security, symfony, annotations

I'm trying to use the JMS security bundle on my controllers, but it doesnt work.
I include all the required bundles

```
//...
new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
//...
```

Here is my config

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    enable_iddqd_attribute: false
    expressions: true
    voters:
        disable_authenticated: false
        disable_role:          false
        disable_acl:           false
    method_access_control: { }
    util:
        secure_random:
            connection: default
            table_name: security_users
```

And here is my really basic controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("", name="interne_homepage")
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('App/homepage.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Whatever role I try, it is never blocked, access always granted. What did I do wrong ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you configure the firewall for the specified route in the `security.yml`?

Comment: Do i have to specify every route in which I want to use it ? Isnt there some kind of generic service ?

Comment: I think you must put the route under a firewall, you can define in the `access_control` section a roule for every path. Try change the route in something like secure e define a farewall for it. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but second Google result. I had the same issue and the solution is: clear your cache (php app/console cache:clear)